# STUN/TURN/ICE implementation with Ejabberd server and XMPP client iOS

Tags: ios, ejabberd, xmppframework, stun, turn

I am using `ejabberd-16.04` on my mac and `XMPPFramework` from **robbiehanson**.

It works fine for chatting, no problem.

But now I want to add voice calling into my application.
I am using `Jingle Protocol` for call establishment and it works fine for direct communication (i.e. both caller and callee are in same network).

The problem I am facing is for cross-network and I want to implement `Jingle ICE` for this, NATed clients.

1 Can any one tell me how can I enable and use STUN/TURN module on `ejabberd server` and same thing at client side.
1.1 Iam also facing problems with `urn:xmpp:extdisco:2` for external service discovery.

2 Is there any library for XMPP which implements `Jingle-ICE` for iOS?

Comment: Regarding ejabberd, you can indeed enable STUN/TURN from server. You would need specific library and code on client. I do not think XMPPFramework supports this out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I come to know that community addition of ejabberd doesn't provide STUN/TURN. So is there any other open source TURN server which can work with jabbed? Client side coding I think won't make more trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The community version of ejabberd includes STUN and TURN.
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#stun-and-turn
You'll need to configure SRV records for both STUN and TURN in order for client discovery of STUN/TURN to work correctly.
http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records#STUN_SRV_records

The only significant limitation is that TURN Authentication does not work with SCRAM password storage.