# How to configure / debug TURN using ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, stun, turn

I want to configure STUN/TURN in ejabberd in order to use WebRTC with 'Conversations' XMPP client.

Of course I read [ejabberd STUN/TURN documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen/#ejabberd-stun-1) and how to [configure DNS SRV records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302740/stun-turn-ice-implementation-with-ejabberd-server-and-xmpp-client-ios). I also temporarily set [authentication to anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785873/enable-stun-turn-feature-in-ejabberd/38642552#38642552). According to the gist [A/V calls in Conversations](https://gist.github.com/iNPUTmice/a28c438d9bbf3f4a3d4c663ffaa224d9) I tested ICE / STUN / TURN with `adb logcat` and [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/).

My problem is: I do see "discovered ICE servers" and "STUN candidate" with type "srflx" (so I think STUN works correctly), but there is no "candidate" with type "relay", I just get type "host". Sometimes(!) I get the notification: "Not reachable?"

My config (ejabberd.yml):

'listen' is configured for udp and tcp, both with `use_turn: true`

'mod_stun_disco' contains four entries: `type: stun` and `turn` and `transport: udp` and `tcp`, all with identical IP and portnumber, matching the DNS SRV records.

```
listen:
  -
  port: 43210
  transport: udp
  module: ejabberd_stun
  use_turn: true
  ## The server's public IPv4 address:
  turn_ip: 123.123.123.123 # Servers real IPv4 IP
  auth_type: anonymous


mod_stun_disco:
  services:
    -
      host: 123.123.123.123 # Servers real IPv4 IP
      port: 43210
      type: turn
      transport: udp
```

So my last possible source of trouble is:
I'm using a 'beginners friendly' managed hosting provider where I only have an unprivileged user account (Fedora). 
So I built and run ejabberd as a user and had to open several custom firewall ports: c2s, s2s_in, https, with and without TLS (and 'let's encrypt' certificate).
But AFAICS everything works fine, everything except TURN.
Of course I have no rights to run tcpdump to analyze TCP / UDP Traffic, but in ejabberd.log there I can find:

`[info] @mod_stun_disco:handle_call:332 Offering STUN/TURN services to user@server.tld/Conversations.AbCD`

And when I increase the loglevel to `debug`, with a real XMPP-Client there are 'Send XML on stream' entries with "reading that 'Relay candidate harvesting in WebRTC only works with credentials.', I changed `auth: anonymous` to `user` and provided the plaintext-credentials of a valid testuser to TrickleICE, and now I only see 'Not an ephemeral username' in my log.

So my question is:
What to try next?
Does anyone know whats going wrong?
Or is there a way to dig deeper into debugging?

Comment: This tutorial on configuring STUN/TURN in ejabberd should be quite helpful during your debugging: https://www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-set-up-ejabberd-video-voice-calling/

Comment: Thanks, that has been usefull.
"ip: 0.0.0.0" (with adapted IP-Adress) caused a severe "start_error" with "Reason: eaddrnotavail", but after I removed it, I got a step further: Now I see: "accepted long-term STUN authentication".

Comment: Yes, like it's written after that snippet, you should replace "0.0.0.0" with your server IP ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have no knowledge of STUN/TURN, but asked this in the ejabberd chatroom and got two pointers:

Licaon_Kter said:

> firewall for turn range 49xxx-65000

Holger said:

> 49152-65535 *UDP* must be accessible, plus 43210 *UDP* with his
>   config.
>
> And he should revert his fiddling: `auth_type` must be kept to the
>   default (`user`) and he should just do `mod_stun_disco: {}`.
>
> Regarding the UDP port range (49152-65535), he could configure a
>   smaller range, e.g. `turn_min_port: 60000` and `turn_max_port: 60999`.
>   But he does need more than one or two ports.

If you have more doubts, you can join the ejabberd chatroom at ejabberd@conference.process-one.net

Comment: I joined the room, thanks for pointing to it.
I registered at Stackoverflow because https://docs.ejabberd.im/ say's to "Ask questions" here, so this is confusing.

I'm not really shure if it is solved, but opening several ports (why so many?) in the firewall for TURN obviously is important but not documented (https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen/#ejabberd-stun-1)